# Status bar for Linux console?

Tags: arch-linux, console

I spend quite a bit of time in the Linux console. I like the no-distractions interface, but I would really appreciate a way to show at least the battery level, date, and time, and ideally also CPU/RAM usage stats, CPU temperature, and network status in a status bar. Basically I want this in the console:

[image: RAM usage, load average, CPU temp an usage][image][image: WiFi, volume, and battery indicators]

(those are the relevant pieces of my GNOME top bar)

I also want to be able to set a custom strftime-style string for the time/date display. Integration with something like tmux or screen, letting me show which shell I have open, would be great. Is there anything that does this?

A minimalistic GUI isn't a solution, because I don't want to be able to run GUI browsers.

Comment: (I know I need to charge my laptop :-D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Byobu](https://www.byobu.org/), a wrapper for tmux and screen, comes with a nice status bar with fairly broad set of items it can show there. Here's how it looks like for me (using defaults):

[image]

(Showing distro, release,  window details, pending package updates, uptime, CPU temperature, load, and usage, RAM and storage usage, hostname and date)

You can run `byobu-config` to add additional details, [generated by a number of scripts](https://github.com/dustinkirkland/byobu/tree/master/usr/lib/byobu). I haven't tried these, but they include `network`, `wifi_quality`, and `battery`. I don't see a way to provide a custom format string for date/time, but you can include [the output of custom commands](https://github.com/dustinkirkland/byobu/blob/master/usr/lib/byobu/custom#L29) by putting scripts in `~/.byobu/bin` which match the glob `[0-9]*_*` (e.g., `00_my_date`). So you could disable the built-in date and time options, and use a script to print the date and time the way you want it.

(You could also look through what byobu does to generate the status line and make your own, which shouldn't need as much complexity as byobu's.)

Answer (score 0):

`i3` is a tiling window manager that I love to use.  It's similar to tmux in that you can create/rearrange tiled consoles with ease.

With `i3` there are several components that you can choose to add.  A relevant one is `i3status` which is a status bar which displays whatever you like.

[image]

I also use `dmenu` which runs whenver I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. That lets me enter a command which may open another tiled window.  If you want to restrict your users to console-only, then you don't need to include `dmenu`.  Instead, the default behaviour is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will open a new terminal.  Of course, there is nothing stopping you from running `firefox &` in that terminal to create a firefox window.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I have looked at i3 before, but I'm looking for something that runs directly in the virtual console; i3 seems to be X-based?

Comment: Correct, i3 is X-based.  Maybe it'll help someone else who finds this question.